# Does BitmapDescriptorFactory provides caching?

Tags: android, google-maps, caching

I am using `Google Maps v2` in `Android` project, I want to put markers with custom icons on the map, so I want to use [`BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/BitmapDescriptorFactory.html).

My question is: "Does BitmapDescriptorFactory caches resources, or I should do it myself?"

I think, guys from Android Google Maps team should know that.

Here is documentation for [`BitmapDescriptorFactory`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/BitmapDescriptorFactory.html) and there is no notice about caching.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on a number of icons you can reuse you will probably get better performance if you cache them yourself.

In my tests retrieving the very same icon 10 000 times by using BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource() took 1s 220 ms compared to 25 ms if you just return it from your cache.

Anyway it is useful to profile an app and see if it is a bottleneck.